# Api query from mongodb Show TypeError: null is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mean-stack

```
router.get('/player', function(req, res) { 
    players.find(null) 
           .then(data =>{ 
               res.json({ confirmation: 'success', data: data }) 
           })
           .catch(err =>{ 
               res.json({ confirmation: 'fail', message: err.message }) 
           }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `players.find({})` if you want all results.